# how to make pandas read_csv handle numpy str (or unicode) scalar datatypes

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pandas

Whenever I read a CSV file that has a column of strings, I've found that by default `pandas` gives it's `dtype` as `object`. I've tried to use `mydf['mycol'].astype(str)` to change the `dtype` of a column `mycol` from `object` to `str`, but it didn't work - it didn't give me an error, but at the same time, the `dtype` remained the same.

I read that `pandas` has been built on top of `numpy`, and `numpy` allows for both `str_` and `unicode_` [see here: numpy scalar types](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html#arrays-scalars-built-in). I'm NOT very familiar with the internal workings of `pandas` and NOT familiar with `numpy` in general.

1. Is there anything I can do when using `pandas.io.parsers.read_csv` to make sure that a column of strings in the CSV file is read as a `dtype` of `str` rather than `object`?

More specifically, what parameters (from those given below) do I need to use to achieve this?

```
pandas.io.parsers.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep=', ', dialect=None, 
   compression=None, doublequote=True, escapechar=None, quotechar='"', quoting=0, 
   skipinitialspace=False, lineterminator=None, header='infer', index_col=None, 
   names=None, prefix=None, skiprows=None, skipfooter=None, skip_footer=0, 
   na_values=None, na_fvalues=None, true_values=None, false_values=None, 
   delimiter=None, converters=None, dtype=None, usecols=None, engine=None, 
   delim_whitespace=False, as_recarray=False, na_filter=True, compact_ints=False, 
   use_unsigned=False, low_memory=True, buffer_lines=None, warn_bad_lines=True, 
   error_bad_lines=True, keep_default_na=True, thousands=None, comment=None, 
   decimal='.', parse_dates=False, keep_date_col=False, dayfirst=False, 
   date_parser=None, memory_map=False, float_precision=None, nrows=None, 
   iterator=False, chunksize=None, verbose=False, encoding=None, squeeze=False, 
   mangle_dupe_cols=True, tupleize_cols=False, infer_datetime_format=False, 
   skip_blank_lines=True)
```

2. Somewhat related: is there any variable / flag in the parameters of `pandas.io.parsers.read_csv` that can automatically read a missing string from a column of string as `''` (empty string) rather than read a missing string as `nan`?

Also, many of the parameters that can be passed to `pandas.io.parsers.read_csv` are NOT described in the documentation : [pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) for example, `na_fvalues`, `use_unsigned`, `compact_ints`, etc. Aside from reading the code (which is a bit long), would there be any ohter place where a more detailed documentation for all the parameters is available?

Comment: You're are sorely mistaken `object` is just the dtype describing the array type, it is being stored as `str`, you don't need to do anything here

Comment: You can pass the dtypes as a dict as a param to `read_csv` by default a column composing of empty data will be treated as float so that `NaN` can be represented

Comment: I don't want to pass the `dtypes` as I don't know the columns ahead of time.

Comment: not sure if you are right about "`object` is just the dype desribing the array type, it is being stored as `str`" part. as per http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html#arrays-scalars-built-in `object` is a different dtype than `str_` and the two aren't even related by parent/child except by `generic`. do you have any reference / documentation that says "`object` is just the dype desribing the array type, it is being stored as `str`"  ?

Comment: Try `na_filter=False`

Comment: Try this to convince yourself: `df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['asdas']})
type(df.iloc[0]['a'])`

Comment: but then why is the `str` column displayed with a dtype of `object` considering that they are only connected by `np.generic` and are not parent / child classes of each other ?

Comment: @EdChum, thanks for the `na_filter` suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a technical decision taken by Wes **not** to use numpy's string datatype: Numpy allocates all strings as the same size.

In most real world use cases strings are not fixed size and often a few are very long. It's wasteful to allocate a very large contiguous block of memory (and IIRC, 
counterintuitively, can be slower!) to store them as if they are fixed size:

```
In [11]: np.array(["ab", "a"])  # The 2 is the length
Out[11]:
array(['ab', 'a'],
      dtype='|S2')

In [12]: np.array(['this is a very long string', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
Out[12]:
array(['this is a very long string', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
      dtype='|S26')
```

---

To give a silly example, we can see an example where object dtype takes up less memory:

```
In [21]: a = np.array(['a'] * 99 + ['this is a very long string, really really really really really long, oh yes'])

In [22]: a.nbytes
Out[22]: 7500

In [23]: b = a.astype(object)

In [24]: b.nbytes + sum(sys.getsizeof(item) for item in b)
Out[24]: 4674
```

---

There's also some "surprising" behaviour of numpy strings (also due to their layout):

```
In [31]: a = np.array(['ab', 'c'])

In [32]: a[1] = 'def'

In [33]: a  # what the f?
Out[33]:
array(['ab', 'de'],
      dtype='|S2')
```

*If you wanted to fix this behaviour - and keep the numpy string dtype - you would have to make a copy for every assignment. (With object arrays you get this for free: you simply change the pointer.)*

---

Hence in pandas strings are stored using the object dtype.

*Note: I thought there was a section of the docs which discussed this decision but I can't seem to locate it...*

Comment: Hmmm in this example it makes it look like this is even close, I think in the real world it's not: in general object is significantly smaller.

Comment: I tried `a=np.array(["abc","de","y"])`, `b=a.astype(object)`, `for item in b: print(sys.getsizeof(item))` and I get 52, 51, 54 corresponding to "abc", "de", "y". Would you know why the size didn't reduce even though the characters in the strings reduced?

Comment: @uday That's bizarre. (in python 2) I get [40, 39, 38] and [56, 54, 52] for unicode - different to you. I was wondering if perhaps getsizeof is not necessarily accurate here? Note: the first 40 or 50 (for unicode) bytes is overhead for the python object, the difference is then the data (where the actual string points to), so you should see the difference being what you'd expect (though some unicode characters are longer than others).

Comment: thanks for sharing the second example. that is definitely a deal breaker. I found that on my machine, generally, if the string sizes are more or less of the same length, the string version of `np.array` takes less memory than the `object` version. E.g.  for `a=numpy.array(["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"])` ,  `a.nbytes` gives 104, while `b.nbytes+sum(sys.getsizeof(item) for item in b)` gives 1612. Still haven't been able to figure out the formula for the byte size of `object` class. may be it's an issue of PY2 vs PY3

Comment: @uday I have a feeling the getsizeof is pessimistic (the thing to also remember is that for numpy it has to be contiguous so in real examples it's actually quite easy to run out of memory - because you don't have such a large block free - but you would have lots of little blocks) I really wouldn't worry about this difference too much :)